# Preserving uniqueness for overlapping points when converting from points to raster?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, overlapping-features, hydrology, rasterization, focal-statistics

I'm trying to optimize outflow points based on lowest elevation within some tolerance. Using the SnapPourPoint function which does exactly this, but outputs a raster file. I've been converting this raster back to points using RasterToPoint however it creates an issue when multiple points that are within close proximity and snap to the same raster cell. The resulting RasterToPoint output will only preserve one of the points. Points sharing the same minimum elevation are to be expected, but I would like to preserve a unique identifier for each point, is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Snap_editing a (copy of?) original to pour points

Comment: This will generally work, however there are some instances where the nearest pour point to the original is not always the respective minimum elevation within the tolerance

Answer (score 1):

You could use the USGS [*Split by Attribute*](http://www.umesc.usgs.gov/management/dss/split_by_attribute_tool.html) tool to separate each pour point to its own file. Then run the *SnapPourPoint* tool, convert back to point with the *RasterToPoint* tool. Finally, use the *Merge* tool to combine all pour points to the same file.